# Clean up installation after incomplete / interrupted setup

Tags: windows, installation, cleaning

The setup of an arbitrary application was interrupted, and the name of it does not appear in the "Add or Remove Program" list. I've tried to use the Windows Installer CleanUp Utility from Microsoft but the utility can't be used if the item doesn't appear in "Add or Remove Programs".

How can I remove the leftover items from the system?

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to answer accurately without knowing what program you're referring to, but one option would be to install the program again to completion, then uninstall it.

If the installer won't install the program because it thinks it's already installed (whew), you can try using the [Windows Installer CleanUp Utility](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290301) to mark the program as not installed.  After you do this, the installer might let you continue normally.

Comment: The problem is that setup cannot be completed , because ( as I think ) previous setup of the same app was interrupted.

Answer (score 0):

[Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/) The main feature of Revo Uninstaller is to remove unnecessary files and registry entries left behind by incomplete program uninstallation routines. But it is also as alternative Add/Remove programs in Windows

Comment: Thanks for posting a link to a potentially helpful program. On Super User, we tend to discourage answers with just a link and no explanation. Your answer would be more useful to the community if you [edited](http://superuser.com/posts/233742/edit) it to add a bit more detail about what Revo Uninstaller is and does, and perhaps a link to their official website rather than the Wikipedia entry. Thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this tool from Microsoft: `MicrosoftProgram_Install_and_Uninstall` https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed.

Select `uninstall` when asked which one you are facing a problem with, and then select your program from the list..